# Test index within bounds of list

Tags: java-8

*First of all, I want to share that i'm an experienced Java developer and that this isn't a newbie question.*

We all know the test to check if a given index is within the bounds of a `List`. Namely:

```
if (index >= 0 && index < list.size())
```

I was wondering if the introduction of Java 8 created some new method somewhere that could do this test. Something like:

```
if (list.isWithinBounds(index))
```

Google gave me no results and I can't find any method in the new APIs. So maybe the community knows if there's something available like this.

I'm not interested in third party libraries which solved this.

Comment: And this is somewhere catching `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is out of place?

Comment: AFAIK no, but it's simple to write a utility method if you need. I find `if (index >= 0 && index < list.size())` short and clear personally.

Comment: Actually my goal is mainly improving readability and prevent errors by somehow making a mistake writing this test. I believe that using exception handling in this case would dramatically lower readability and would even create a performance hit.

Comment: The problem I see is that not knowing whether your index is valid or not is a bit of a *code smell*. Is this the result of some user input?

Comment: @ChristopherS: the big question is why should any programmer do this test? What is the intended action if the test fails? Normally, an appropriate exception should be thrown to flag the erroneous index. This is what the `List` implementation already does for you.

Comment: It's 'kind of' user input. It's input coming from a website which can be manipulated through faking the http request. Apart from that, I want the system to take no action if it receives an invalid index. It doesn't need to throw an exception (because there is no reason to give feedback to the user in this use case).

Comment: So the simple answer is, no, there is no such method and I doubt that there ever will be. If that task appears that often in your code, create your own utility method. If you want to use Java 8 features to lower the complexity of the condition, use `Integer.compareUnsigned(index, list.size())<0`…

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer - just an extra option for helper method placement in java 8. No way to easily attach the helper interface though, so is not a viable solution.

```
public interface MyList<E> extends List<E> {
    default boolean isWithinBounds(int index) {
        return 0 <= index && index < this.size();
    }
}

static class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> implements MyList<E> {
}

public void testList() {
    MyList<String> l = new MyArrayList<>();
    l.add("1");
    l.add("2");
    l.add("3");
    assert(l.isWithinBounds(2));
    assert(!l.isWithinBounds(3));
}
```